# No such file or directory! , but the directory is there

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to import some .dat file from a folder "input" which has the files, and this directory exists, but every time executing the code, it gives me this error:

```
Failed to open HRG Pressure: No such file or directory
```

This the path specified: `HRG_press=input/Press_HRG_MUB000601_T005300_dT1.dat`, `HRG_press_SN=input/Press_HRG_MUB000601_T005300_dT1_SN.dat`.

Code fragment:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "Importing HRG Pressure \n");
    
    FILE *FilePressHRG;

    if (!strange)
        FilePressHRG = fopen(HRG_press, "r");
    else
        FilePressHRG = fopen(HRG_press_SN, "r"); 
    
    if (FilePressHRG == NULL)
        err(1, "Failed to open HRG Pressure.\n");

    for (i = 0, x2int = 0; fscanf(FilePressHRG,"%lf %lf %lf\n", &xIn1, &xIn2, &xIn3) != EOF; i++) {
        x1int = (i % 817) + 5;
        PressHRGMat[x1int][x2int] = xIn3 * pow(x1int, 4);
        if (x1int == 821)
            x2int++;
    }
    fclose(FilePressHRG);
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241432/discussion-on-question-by-random-guy-no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-direct).

Answer (score 1):

Print a *useful* error message:

---

```
void do_hrg_file( int strange)
{
char *the_name;
FILE * FilePressHRG;


fprintf(stderr,"Importing HRG Pressure \n");

the_name = strange ? HRG_press_SN : HRG_press;
FilePressHRG = fopen(the_name, "r");

if (FilePressHRG==NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open `%s' for HRG Pressure.\n", the_name);
        err(1, "OMG Pressure!\n");
        }

for(i=0, x2int=0; fscanf(FilePressHRG,"%lf %lf %lf\n", &xIn1, &xIn2, &xIn3) != EOF;i++){
    x1int = (i % 817) + 5;
    PressHRGMat[x1int][x2int] = xIn3 * pow(x1int, 4);
    if(x1int == 821) x2int++;
}

fclose(FilePressHRG); 
return;
}
```

---

I used quotes to print the offending filename. Errors like this are often caused by leading or trailing spaces in the pathname. [BTW: you could print the current directory, too, using `pwd()`. Or you could use an absolute pathname for the file.]

Comment: I was about to remark that this is not responsive to the question, but then I saw that it's not clear what the question actually is.  If it is "why isn't my program working?" then this doesn't cut it, but if it's "How do I troubleshoot this?" then this does speak to it.